# Iterating over base type properties first when calling Reflection's GetMembers?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to iterate over all the members of a given type. This interaction must support inheritance, since most type will be extended as necessary.

I've just found out that the order in which types present themselves when iterating over GetMembers isn't really what I'd expect -- the types of the derived classes appear first, in their current order, and the types of the base classes later, again in their current order.

Source:

```
using System;

class Program 
{
        class SomeClass
        {
            public string First { get; set; }
            public int Second;
        }

        class AnotherClass : SomeClass
        {
            public int Third { get; set; }
            public string Fourth;
        } 

        public static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new AnotherClass { First = "asd", Second = 10};

            foreach (var member in obj.GetType().GetMembers())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(member.Name);
            }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
    get_Third
    set_Third
    get_First
    set_First
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
    .ctor
    Third
    First
    Fourth
    Second
```

You can check a run [here](http://ideone.com/IPNyx).

I'd like to invert this situation, using reflection to get only types from the base class, then from the derived. Is there any way to do this?

Another question on the same line: when searching members, properties come first and fields second. Anyway to change this behavior as well, or the metadata created will always present in that order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the base type use [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) property.

To check if a member is declared in the same type, use [DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) property:

```
public static bool DeclaredInType(Type typeToCheck, MemberInfo member)
{
    return typeToCheck.Equals(member.DeclaringType);
}
```

EDIT: you can sort by type by using LINQ:

```
public static MemberInfo[] SortMembers(IEnumerable<MemberInfo> members)
{
    return members.OrderBy(m => m.GetType().Name)
                  .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems simple enough. I will try that.

Comment: It works alright, and just now I understood what you said about checking the declaring type. Completely necessary, otherwise I'd get all the types over and over again. One question: anyway to ask reflection to not give me inherited types (through the binding flags, for example)? I've tried it but was unable to.

Comment: @Bruno Brant This is almost two years late, but you can filter that using the BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to the OP (and I'm a bit late for that), but I'll just describe what I did, in the hopes someone may find it helpful.

I have a home-made program that serializes to XML. It is driven by a List of CopierField objects that I create that contain the data I need to expedite the serialization. Here is a much-redacted version of that class:

```
  private class CopierField
  {
     // Name of the field or property and a reference to the declaring Type
     public string MemberName;
     public Type DeclaringType;

     // Reference to the FieldInfo or PropertyInfo object for this field or property. One of 
     //  these will be null and the other non-null.
     public FieldInfo MemberInfoForField = null;
     public PropertyInfo MemberInfoForProperty = null;

     // Ordering of this field, as returned by Type.GetMembers(). This is only used while 
     //  building the List<> of these objects for XML serialization
     public int FieldOrder;


     /// <summary>
     /// Comparison method that can be used to sort a collection of CopierField objects so they 
     /// are in the order wanted for XML serialization. This ordering is dependent on the depth 
     /// of derivation, and when that is equal it maintains the original ordering.
     /// </summary>
     public static readonly Comparison<CopierField> CompareForXml =
                        delegate(CopierField a, CopierField b)
                        {
                           int aDepth = GetTypeDepth(a.DeclaringType);
                           int bDepth = GetTypeDepth(b.DeclaringType);
                           if (aDepth != bDepth)
                              return aDepth.CompareTo(bDepth);

                           return a.FieldOrder.CompareTo(b.FieldOrder);
                        };


     /// <summary>
     /// Method to determine the depth of derivation for a type.
     /// </summary>
     private static int GetTypeDepth(Type aType)
     {
        int i = 0;
        while (aType.BaseType != null)
        {
           i++;
           aType = aType.BaseType;
        }
        return i;
     }
  }
```

Before serializing an object type to XML the first time I create a List of these objects sorted in the order I want using a method somewhat like this, where the input is a List of the CopierField objects that is based on data from Type.GetMembers().

```
  private static List<CopierField> CreateCopierFieldListForXml(List<CopierField> copierFields)
  {
     // Build the new list, and note the original ordering as created by Type.GetMembers()
     List<CopierField> copierFieldsForXml = new List<CopierField>(copierFields.Count);
     for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < copierFields.Count; listIndex++)
     {
        CopierField copierField = copierFields[listIndex];
        copierField.FieldOrder = listIndex;
        copierFieldsForXml.Add(copierField);
     }

     // Sort the new list as wanted for XML serialization
     copierFieldsForXml.Sort(CopierField.CompareForXml);
     return copierFieldsForXml;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR

```
    orderby typeof(T).Equals(mi.DeclaringType) ? 1 : -1
```

will push base memberInfo first, and keep the order defined in the class.

Full answer:

to achieve the same goal, and using the DeclaringType as suggested previously, I defined the following method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAllFieldsAndPropertiesOfClass<T>()
    {
        return
            from mi in typeof(T).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
            let ignoreAttr = (IgnoreSerializationAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(mi, typeof(IgnoreSerializationAttribute))
            where (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
               && (ignoreAttr == null || ignoreAttr != null && !ignoreAttr.Ignore)
            orderby typeof(T).Equals(mi.DeclaringType) ? 1 : -1
            select mi;
    }
```

In that method, I also defined a custom attribute to explicitely ignore some properties from the serialization:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class IgnoreSerializationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Ignore { get; private set; }

    public IgnoreSerializationAttribute(bool ignore)
    {
        Ignore = ignore;
    }
}
```

It is also possible to add an other custom Attribute to define the order, e.g.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ColumnOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; private set; }

    public ColumnOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
}
```

used as follow:

```
    public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAllFieldsAndPropertiesOfClassOrdered<T>()
    {
        return
            from mi in GetAllFieldsAndPropertiesOfClass<T>()
            let orderAttr = (ColumnOrderAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(mi, typeof(ColumnOrderAttribute))
            orderby orderAttr == null ? int.MaxValue : orderAttr.Order, mi.Name
            select mi;
    }
```

I am using those methods to serialize list of objects using other objects to CSV files...